# Converting (.net) BsonDocument string into a (java) DBObject

Tags: java, mongodb

In a publishing flow I need to insert a DBObject into a mongo db collection using Java.

I receive the object as a String, and this has been passed to me from a .NET application that used `article.ToBsonDocument().ToJson()` on a POCO.

On my side of the flow, in Java, I tried just using `BasicDBObject doc = (BasicDBObject) JSON.parse(content);` but I get a `com.mongo.util.JSONParseException` on a Date:

```
"CreationDate" : ISODate("2013-03-18T08:50:53Z")
```

I can change how the content is generated in C#, and I can change how to write to the DB in java, my only constraint is that it must be passed as a string between the two systems.

Any suggestions?

**EDIT** Thanks to the tip from @Jim Dagg below, some googling for ISODate and BsonDocument turned out [this gem](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/mongodb-csharp/Leido2oPTKA). Changing the c# code to use

```cs
article.ToBsonDocument().ToJson(new JsonWriterSettings{OutputMode = JsonOutputMode.Strict});
```

fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ISODate` constructor call is what's causing the issue.  From [an issue on the MongoDB JIRA](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/JAVA-565):

> The parser accepts these two date formats: seconds ->
>   `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"` or seconds.milleseconds ->
>   `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"` Just add seconds to your `$date` value
>   and the aggregation command should work. Here's the JSON doc that I
>   had success with: `{ "aggregate" : "test", pipeline : [ {$match : {
>   date : { $date : "2012-05-01T12:30:00Z" } } } ] }`

If you remove the ISODate constructor and simply render your date as (for example) `"2013-03-18T08:50:53Z"`, you should be in business.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I'll have to fiddle with the output of the `.ToJson()` call in c# then.

Comment: Sounds like you could either mess with the method itself (if you have that option available -- I've only worked with the Java driver), or, just find ISODate in the string and blow it away (and its associated parens).

Comment: Looks like there's a way to tell the `ToJson()` extension method to use Strict Json output: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/mongodb-csharp/Leido2oPTKA

Comment: Nice find; that looks like a winner.